# Only want to have positive value for Vector3 - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game which involves scaling the game object and I only want it to have positive values for its Vector3.
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the OnValidate message like this:

```
    private void OnValidate ( )
    {
        if ( ScaleFactor.x < 0 ) ScaleFactor.x = 0;
        if ( ScaleFactor.y < 0 ) ScaleFactor.y = 0;
        if ( ScaleFactor.z < 0 ) ScaleFactor.z = 0;
    }
```

[Here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) the official documentation.